# shiny app gets '400 Bad Request' trying to get data from google api

Tags: r, google-app-engine, http, shiny, ggmap

As part of my shiny app I call `geocode()` from the `ggmap` R package. 
The data is geocoded and gets a result - i can see that from my console trying to run the app locally and from the log on the **shinyapps.io** dash board.
After the end of the geocode i get the next message:

```
.Warning in readLines(connect) :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Error in readLines(connect) : cannot open the connection
```

have a clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So It turns out it has nothing to do with shiny the problam was with sending the data to google's geocode.

When I read in the data I used `read.table()`. Some of the addresses had an apostrophe `'` in them, so it read it as a new line in the same cell (I don't really know why).

I changed the data reading to use `read.csv()` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In `read.table()` default argument for quote is `'` in `read.csv` it is different. Read more about arguments of data input [R: Data Input](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html)